# Including .a libraries in Android

Tags: android, shared-libraries, native

I want to include 6 libraries in Android native code, they are of .a extension

I also want to know the difference between .a and .so libraries, and if there is any dependency on the operating system being running ???

Comment: These are almost certainly not compatible with android and will at minimum need to be recompiled from source with an android-compatible toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between *.a and *.so libraries is that *.a is a static library while *.so is a dynamic one (shared objects). In the case of an archive library *.a the full precompiled source should be there so all you need to do is add

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := yourlib
```

in your Android.mk. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463518/android-ndk-link-using-a-pre-compiled-static-library) for more details.